# Set validation for dynamic field

Tags: angularjs

I have a form where the user can add fields dynamically. It is my html:

```
<body ng-controller="FruitController">
    <button type="button" ng-click="addFruit()">Add fruit</button>
    <form name="list">
      <div id="dynamicList" ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
        <input type="text" name="fruitName" ng-model="fruit.name" ng-minlength="3"/>
      </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

And it is my controller:

```
app.controller('FruitController', [function(){

  $scope.fruits = [
    {name: 'Apple', color: 'red'} 
  ];

  $scope.addFruit = function()
  {
    $scope.fruits.push({name: '', color: ''});
  };
}]);
```

So, when a field is invalid i add a css class with the next directive:

```
ng-class="{'uk-form-danger': (list.fruitName.$invalid && !list.fruitName.$pristine)}"
```

The problem is that, when 1 field fails, another fields too.
Any ideas ?

Comment: where you are trying to add this `ng-class` condition?

Comment: @pankajparkar i am adding the `ng-class` condition into the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form inside `ng-repeat` won't work directly. You need to create a a separate form for inner elements that form will be child of outer form `list`

```
<form name="list">
  <div id="dynamicList" ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
   <form name="innerForm">
    <input type="text" name="fruitName" ng-model="fruit.name" ng-minlength="3" 
     ng-class="{'uk-form-danger': (innerForm.fruitName.$invalid && !fruit.name.$pristine)}"/>
   </form>
  </div>
</form>
```